# How to integrate Twilio with AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, twilio

I am using Twilio in my web app and want to have SCA requirements and want to explore AD B2C. Any quick references or samples for this?

Comment: Hi @Veronica are you looking to Integrating Twilio Verify App with Azure Active Directory B2C.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate Twilio payment app in Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) with the Twilio Verify API. By using Twilio Verify App, Azure AD B2C customers can comply with PSD2 (Payment Services Directive 2) transaction requirements through dynamic linking and strong customer authentication.

If you want a tutorial for this, you can see [Integrating Twilio Verify App with Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/partner-twilio)

You can find one of the code samples for Twilio and B2C integration is [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/twilio-mfa-psd2).